# Partition assignment in ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer is empty [ ] for 2/3 threads while I am trying to set concurrency to 3

Tags: spring-kafka

Because the response topic is empty, when trying to send 3 requests simultaneously only one is getting a response.

Below is the concurrent listener container:

```
@Bean
    public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> replyListenerContainer() {
        ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(replyTopic);
        containerProperties.setGroupId(returnGroup);

        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> kafkaMessageListenerContainer =
            new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<>(consumerFactory(), containerProperties);
        kafkaMessageListenerContainer.setConcurrency(3);
        return kafkaMessageListenerContainer;
    }
```

I am expecting that all 3 requests should complete sequentially.

Comment: The concurrency is not more than number of partitions in the topic you are assigning. So, if that one topic with one partition, only one thread is going to be busy

Comment: so this is the expected behavior, right? if so, is there a way where I can get all 3 responses sequentially .

Comment: because in code documentation, it is mentioned as/**
  * The maximum number of concurrent {@link KafkaMessageListenerContainer}s running.
  * Messages from within the same partition will be processed sequentially.
  * @param concurrency the concurrency.
  */

Comment: The “sequentially” is an opposite to “parallel”. Do, what is your concern with an expected behavior?

Comment: what I m trying to ask that Is there any way in which all 3 concurrent listener containers got assigned Topic on App startup (and single partition in my case). so that my CompletableFuture will dump each request one by one(bcz i m processing 3 request sequentially on one consumer and response is also coming on same partition) . Does this make sense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Artem said, each partition can have only one consumer (per consumer group).

If the topic has only one partition, there can be only one consumer.

It makes no sense at all to have a replying container receive multiple copies of the reply.

If you have 3 consumers on the topic and want to wait for 3 replies, the next release (2.3) will have an `AggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#aggregatingreplyingkafkatemplate